# SOAP: Invalid HTTPS client certificate path

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, https

When I run the below-given code, the error `ERROR: Invalid HTTPS client certificate path` is generated. I checked that the path to certificate.pem and test.wsdl is correct. What might be the reason of such error?

```
$wsdl = 'http://localhost:10088/test/test.wsdl';

$options = array(
    'local_cert' => 'http://localhost:10088/test/certificate.pem',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
);


try {
    $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl, $options);
    $result = $client->getLastResponse();
    print_r($result);
} catch (SoapFault $s) {
    die('ERROR: [' . $s->faultcode . '] ' . $s->faultstring);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for the option `local_cert` must be a file path instead of an URL. Change the code to this for `$options`:

```
$options = array(
    'local_cert' => '/path_where_cert_is_stored/certificate.pem',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
);
```

Since the documentation for [Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html) isn't complete, you can look at [PHP: SOAP - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) for more information, because this what `Zend_Soap_Client` uses under the hood. In my opinion the possible arguments are better described at [PHP: SoapClient::SoapClient - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) (especially look at the example).